# Chinese technology indices

Tags: stocks, index-fund, china

Is there a Chinese stock index comparable to the [NASDAQ 100](https://www.nasdaq.com/markets/indices/nasdaq-100.aspx) or [NASDAQ Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ_Composite) covering Chinese technology stocks with the highest market cap? And are there corresponding ETFs or Mutual Funds?

Answer (score 1):

The [Guggenheim China Technology ETF](http://www.etf.com/CQQQ) is exactly what I was looking for.